# What is the good way to store images for testing upload and removal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, carrierwave, fixtures

What is the good way to store images for testing upload and removal ?

- I am using Carrierwave to upload my images
- RSpec for my features spec

I wrote some fixtures for my products.

Product has attached images which are stored in a folder
`spec/fixtures/product/attachments/pull_noir_1.jpg`

When I launch the **delete a product spec**, the image is removed from the folder, and then, the next  spec fails, because the image can't be found (Yes it has been removed)... `public/uploads/product/attachments/683902633/pull_rouge_1.jpg`

How am I supposed to set my uploader and where should I keep the images?

Here are some of my fixtures
**products.yml**

```
warm_sweat:
  title: Gros pull
  price: 30
  color: Noir
  category: pull
  user: nelly
  attachments: pull_rouge_1.jpg

black_k_l:
  title: Pull Kenzaro
  price: 20
  color: Noir
  category: pull
  user: nelly
  attachments: pull_noir_1.jpg
```

My **attachement_uploader.rb**

```
class AttachmentUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  if Rails.env.production?
    storage :fog
  else
    storage :file
  end

  version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fill: [280, 280]
   end

  def default_url(*args)
     "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "random.jpg"].compact.join('_')
   end

  def store_dir      
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

> EDIT  I re added the `#{model.id}` Still facing the same probleme

The failures

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
           No route matches [GET] /uploads/product/attachments/683902633/pull_rouge_1.jpg
```

I don't think you need my specs but feel free to ask if I have to update the question with more code.

Comment: Your `store_dir` isn't unique across records, so that once a record deleted, the reference for others lost. You can use `"uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"` to solve this

Comment: P/S: This trouble is not only happen on your test environment but also production as well ( if you don't use 3rd service such as S3 ), so you have to make the `store_dir` to be unique.

Comment: I have the same probleme even with the `#{model.id}`

Comment: Did you check and restart your `spring` ? Sometime it's not updated as expected. If you change the uploader, but the error still print out the same URL, then the application doesn't update yet.

Comment: Yes I restarted spring :)

Comment: the folder `683902633` is not added automatically ? I have to do it manually ? (btw I did that but it doesn't change anything)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My rails_helper was missing this:

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.root              = Rails.root.join('spec/fixtures')
  config.cache_only        = true
  config.enable_processing = false
  config.base_path         = "/"
end
```